# Vim: Begin insert on new line in same column as cursor

Tags: haskell, vim

Haskell has a language feature called guards that look like this (starting with the '`|`'):

```
powMod a p m | odd p = (a * powMod asq halfp m) `polyMod` m
             | otherwise = powMod asq halfp m
    where
        halfp = p `div` 2
        asq = (a*a) `polyMod` m
```

Proper style requires that you keep the guards in multiple lines aligned with each other.  When I'm typing source code, I tend to enter the first line of a function definition with a guard, hit enter, then messily `tab`, `space`, and `backspace` my way around until I get the cursor aligned under the first '`|`'.  I would prefer to position my cursor over the first '`|`' (with '`F|`' or something similar), then do something simple to open a new line and start inserting at the same column, without autoindent forcing the cursor to retreat to the left margin and without any messy manual alignment.

What is this simple thing I need to do to begin an insert on the next line in the same column?

Comment: Consider moving this to the new vim SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your exact question

> I would prefer to position my cursor over the first '|' (with 'F|' or something similar), then do something simple to open a new line and start inserting at the same column

You can set `virtualedit`. This allows you to move the cursor everywhere regardless you reached the end of a line or not (I can't live without it now). This way, once you are on the `|` you just need to press `ji` (go down and start inserting).

Once you've done this, using `autoindent` make each newline start at the same indentation as the previous line.

Another way is to use virtual block `Ctrl-V` , go down a few lines and press `r|`. This will draw a vertical line of `|`.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a very similar question on Superuser some time ago:

> [How to align the cursor under a specific character?](https://superuser.com/q/685828/162491)

There is another solution though, that I somewhat prefer: The problem with this style of alignment is that if you change the name of the function, the names of the variables etc., you need to change the indentation of the whole block, which is troublesome especially when sending patches to version controlled projects etc. An alternative is to add new-lines and just one step indentation as in

```
powMod a p m
    | odd p = (a * powMod asq halfp m) `polyMod` m
    | otherwise = powMod asq halfp m
  where
    halfp = p `div` 2
    asq = (a*a) `polyMod` m
```

And if the patterns themselves get too complex, like when using [pattern guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard), the equations can be again indented, as in

```
powMod a p m
    | odd p -- some very long pattern
      = (a * powMod asq halfp m) `polyMod` m
    | otherwise
      = powMod asq halfp m
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the vim plugin [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) to do alignment. There are other plugins like [Align.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) and [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) as well.

If you want to do automatic alignment then add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/haskell.vim`:

```
inoremap <silent> <buffer> <bar> <bar><esc>:call <SID>align()<cr>a
function! s:align()
  if exists(':Tabularize') && line('.') > 1 && getline(line('.') - 1) =~ '|' && getline('.')[0:col('.')] =~ '^\s*|$'
    if getline(line('.') - 1) =~ '^\s*|'
      Tabularize/^\s*\zs|/
    else
      Tabularize/^[^|]*\zs|/
    endif
    normal! 0f|
  endif
endfunction
```

This will align your guards in insert mode on the fly. It requires the tabular plugin. It is based off of Tim Pope's [cucumbertables.vim gist](https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147).

For more help with tabular.vim see the following [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Aligning text with Tabular.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/).